# HttpClient post request with Digest Authentication results in bad request

Tags: c#, authentication, post, hash, httpclient

I am using the following code to extract records from the Dahua XVR camera and it returns records successfully.

```
        var domain = "http://IP";
        var credCache = new CredentialCache();
        credCache.Add(new Uri(domain), "Digest", new 
        NetworkCredential(username, password));
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { 
        Credentials = credCache });
        var result= await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
```

but when I am posting records using the following code it's not working and results in a bad request.

```
        string url = "http://IP/cgi-bin/faceRecognitionServer.cgi";

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "action", "addPerson"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("groupID", "1"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Test Name"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("birthday", "1980-01-05"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sex", "Male"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("country", "Pakistan"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("province", "KPK"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("city", "Peshawar")
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        var domain = "http://IP";
        var credCache = new CredentialCache();
        credCache.Add(new Uri(domain), "Digest", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credCache });
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
```

above code always return 400 bad request. if anyone can help?

Comment: The prbolem is probably connected with url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue as below. Maybe it help someone.

1. reduced the size of the image that I had to embed within the request
   body.
2. concatenated the URL and parameters in a single string.

   ```
      string url = "http://IP/cgi-bin/faceRecognitionServer.cgi? 
                   action=addPerson&groupID=1&name=TestName&sex=Male";

     string domain = "http://IP";
     CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache {
           {
            new Uri(domain), "Digest", new NetworkCredential(username, 
            password)
           }
       };
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { 
    Credentials = credCache });

    using FileStream stream = 


   File.OpenRead(AppContext.BaseDirectory.
   Replace("\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1", "") + "Files\\14.jpg");

   var file_content = new ByteArrayContent(new StreamContent(stream).ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
       file_content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
       var response = await client.PostAsync(url, file_content);
   ```